# Transforming a map with a map of functions in clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to come up with a way to transform a clojure hashmap by applying to each value a function from another map. Here's what I have so far:

```
(defn transform-map [m fm]
  (into {} (for [[k v] m]
    (let [mfn (get fm k identity)] [k (mfn v)])))

(def m {:a 0 :b 0 :c 0 :d 0})
(def fm {:a inc :b dec :c identity})
(transform-map m fm)  ;=> {:a 1, :b -1, :c 0, :d 0}
```

That's works fine, but only so long as each function takes a single argument that is the current value of the key. What if I want to put a function in my function map that uses values other than those in the same key? For example, suppose I want to put the sum of the keys `:a` and `:b` into the key `:d`?

I can try something like:

```
(assoc fm :d (fn[a b] (+ a b)))
```

but is there a way I can alter my `transform-map` function so it will use the appropriate arguments in that function call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to decompose the functions and how they are applicable in the transformation map. Below is an example to show that:

```
;; functions which take some params and return a result
(defn sub [a b] (- a b))
(defn add [a b] (+ a b))

;; data map
(def data {:a 5 :b 4 :c 3})

;; transformation map key => output key, value is vector of function
;; to apply and the params that function will take from the data map
(def transformations {:a [inc :a]
                      :b [dec :b]
                      :c [add :a :b]
                      :d [sub :b :c]})

; The transformation function
(defn transform-map [m fm]
  (into {} (map (fn [[k v]]
                  [k (apply (first v)
                            ((apply juxt (rest v)) m))])
                fm)))

(transform-map data transformations)
```

Comment: I do like this approach, @Ankur. The one shortcoming, IMO though is that since you are `map`ping across the `fm`, you can't automatically pass through the keys in `m` that don't have keys in `fm` to the output. That's pretty easy to rectify though by `merging` in the missing keys. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, in the above implementation, the `transformations` decides the output map keys.

Comment: Hey @Ankur, great answer!  But couldn't you replace ((apply juxt (rest v)) m) with (map (partial get m) (rest v))?  Or, since the built-in map implementations are also callable, you could simplify things further -- (map m (rest v)).  Is there any particular reason why you used juxt?

Comment: @NathanDavis: Hmm no particular reason, may be I tried to give juxt a bit more attention as compared to mr. popular map ;)

Comment: This is a great answer! One cool thing is that `+` and `-` are already functions in clojure, so it would probably be more idiomatic to use those directly rather than the user defined `add` and `sub`.

Answer (score 0):

One more general way to structure this, would be to start with your initial map, and then reduce a collection of transformation functions over it:

"suppose I want to put the sum of the keys :a and :b into the key :d?"

```
user> (def m {:a 0 :b 0 :c 0 :d 0}
#'user/m 
user> (reduce #(%2 %1) m [#(assoc % :a (inc (:a %))) 
                          #(assoc % :b (inc (:b %))) 
                          #(assoc % :d (+ (:a %) (:b %)))]) 
{:a 1, :c 0, :b 1, :d 2}
```

While this is more verbose because you have to specify the action (`assoc`) and the target (`:b` etc. ) for each one, it lets you express any transformation and gives you a place to supply additional arguments. Perhaps more importantly it makes the ordering explicit without  depending on the internal ordering of the map.

You could structure the input as [target action] pairs to make it slightly less verbose:

```
user> (reduce (fn [result [target action]] 
                  (assoc result target (action result))) 
                 m 
                 [[:a #(inc (:a %))] 
                  [:b #(inc (:b %))] 
                  [:d #(+ (:a %) (:b %))]])
{:a 1, :c 0, :b 1, :d 2}
```

Comment: Interesting @Arthur Ufeldt. Is there some way to reduce the redundancy in the first two anonymous function elements of the collection in that `reduce`?

Comment: You could make it less verbose by making it more specific, though it would complicate expressing actions like "a is one more than b".